# Magento 2: placeholder for phone number

Tags: checkout, placeholder

I want to add an example phone number as placeholder for phone number field in billing address. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to file
app/design/frontend/YOUR/THEME/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
<arguments>
    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <!-- The name of the form the field belongs to -->
                                            <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                      <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string">+33234567890</item>
                                                      </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```